# how to make a latching circuit with ground

Tags: relay, latch

I have a pump, represented by a lamp in my schematic, i want this pump to be running once i switch the Activate switch, and when ever an alarm(i have 2 different) is triggered (Alarms are ground) the pump should stop. That is working correctly on the schematic below, there is no complication on that.

My problem is that what i am looking for is that when an alarm is fired then the pump will deactivate and won't activate again even if the alarm goes off, for it to reactivate the activate switch should go off and on again. I have been experimenting with different latching circuits but since the signals are ground i am having a difficult time achieving the result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuUHa6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEMG9s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Tidy up of original circuit. Note how using the ground symbol removes several lines and clarifies the schematic.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsKAHu.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. The revised circuit.*

How it works:

- Closing the Activate switch energises the pump via RLY1's NC contact.
- If either alarm contact closes RLY1 is energised, the pump is disconnected and the relay latches.
- Opening the Activate switch resets the circuit.

Comment: Alarm does not open on fault they close on fault

Comment: Darn. What loolah designs a circuit like that. Revising ...

Comment: Also, i cant make the a tivate a boton since i need to ba able to deactivate it not only by alarm

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Change the text on your revised Figure 2, and this is a brilliant solution

Comment: I imagine a very long ground loop. May need a shunt cap and wetting alarm current must be examined with possible clamp diodes needed for both sensor and pump.

Comment: it is a good solution, my only concern is that i am unsure if i can have ground connected to the alarm, would a diode help there?

Comment: That's an elegant solution.

Comment: @pato.llaguno: What alarm? There is none in your schematic and none mentioned in the text. You have alarm contacts but no alarm.

Comment: @Transistor I mean, when the relay activates the ground will be sent to both alarms and im not sure if that will cause problems to the device sending the alarms, 2 diodes would help this?

Comment: It sounds as though there is something else connected to those contacts that is omitted from your question. Are they not just switching contacts such as in a thermostat?

Comment: they come from a device that manages the alarms, what my understanding is that there is also some indicators like lights and i wouldn't like those to be turned on at the same time, it would defeat the purpose of having 2 different alarms, i might have omitted this info since i tried to simplify the problem

Comment: the alarms are not actually switches, they are just cables with the signal, so to represent it i used a switch