# Control relay with two devices, where one can override the other

Tags: relay

*Disclaimer: I am not an electrical engineer. I understand the logic of what I want, but I do not know which components are available to solve my problem. Please be gentle.*

This is what I have:

1. I have a device A that puts ground (-31) on a wire when in rest. I can deactivate and reactivate this externally, so I can use it like an on/off switch.
2. I have a device B that puts ground (-31) on a wire when it is active and 'nothing' when it is inactive.
3. I have a relay C that connects when it receives a ground (-31), allowing the mechanism behind it to function, like an on/off switch. The relay also receives a +15 as general power supply to do its magic.

This is what I want:
I want to hook up device A and B to the relay C in such a way that:

1. When device B activates, the relay disconnects forever until device A overrides it by being activated (or deactivated and then reactivated, if need be), regardless of the current state of device A.
2. If device B deactivates, the relay is still disconnected. If device B activates again, the relay is still disconnected.
3. When device A deactivates, the relay disconnects until device A reactivates.

Simply put: device A controls the relay and acts as manually operated master override, but device B can interject regardless of the state of device A.

What component(s) do I need between A, B and C to get the behavior I am looking for, and am I making any sense? :)

Timing diagram (edit: now shows system in rest as active as described):
[image: Timing Diagram]

Comment: Might be related to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374264/how-to-make-a-latching-circuit-with-ground), but I honestly can't tell... Sorry.

Comment: I tried to read your question. Sorry. A timing diagram is better than many words. See if you can edit the one I've added to your post. Try to cover every condition that you care about.

Comment: What does *"ground (-31)"* signify?

Comment: When you say "nothing" do you mean disconnected/open, or 0V?

Comment: Ground (-31) is a ground signal like the wire is grounded somewhere, I suppose. Nothing means disconnected/open.
Ah I see what you're doing with the timing diagram, I will have a look at it and correct it if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHwi1N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible solution.*

The trick here is to provide a pulse or "one-shot" when A turns on. You then use this to latch relay C and use B to unlatch relay C. Now due to the pulse action A remaining on will not re-enable C.

- When A turns on the DELAY relay does not energise immediately due to the R1 C2 time delay.
- Current flows through A (NO), DELAY (NC) and RLY-B (NC) and relay C is energised. RLY-C then latches itself on and bypasses the DELAY contact.
- The DELAY relay energises and opens its NC contact but RLY-C is providing the latch.
- C remains on until RLY-B is energised. C then drops out. The latch contact opens and even if B is turned off the C will remain off until the next OFF-ON transition of A.

Be aware that C2 will prevent C being retriggered if A is cycled too quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sure it will work but there are too many components for me to use it practically. I will have to think of something else...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the timing diagram.

[image]

And the relay logic based circuit.

[image]

[image]

A, B and K1 to K6 are standard relays.

C is a magnetic latch relay.

Freewheeling diodes are not shown.

Comment: The timing diagram looks wrong. When A turns the relay into the on position and B triggers, it shouldn't 'flip' the relay back. It should stay active regardless of B's signal. And relay C should be triggered when device B is activated, even if A isn't active.

Comment: According to your description, Relay C is to turn on when Device A is activated and turn off when Device A is deactivated. Relay C is to turn off even when Device B is activated. However your timing diagram contradicts your description by showing Relay C turning on when Device B is activated.

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused (by myself), because the sheer state of device A being hooked up to the system already 'activates' relay C. If device A is detached, relay C closes. So it's like one half is inverted. I will fix the time diagram.

Comment: I fixed the time diagram, sorry for my confusion. Would you mind having another look?

Comment: It tallies with your description one hundred percent and so does my logic!